# WpDataTables - View Image Directory

Tags: plugins, php, mysql

I made a form in PHP and it has an image upload that returns the image name in MySQL, and in the Wp-admin / wordpress folder.

[image]

It is functional, so I created a column with URL Link in DataTables to redirect me to the image directory but it doesn't work.

[image]

**How do I get WpDataTable to read my image directory in the Upload folder?**